# Why is $\frac{1}{16} \sin(\sec^{-1}(\frac{x}{4})) =\frac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}{16x}$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I was requested to solve the integral below, which I show with the solution already.

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-16}}= \frac{1}{16} \sin(\sec^{-1}(\frac{x}{4}))$$

So far so good. However, when corroborating my answer in Symbolab, I found the following transformation:

$$\frac{1}{16} \sin(\sec^{-1}(\frac{x}{4})) =\frac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}{16x}$$

I have no idea where this equality comes from. Though I don't deem it necessary to solve the problems I have, since my solution is already okay, I'm still very curious as to what trigonometric notions are behind it. Would somebody care to explain where the inequality comes from?

Comment: Hint: Let $y = \sec^{-1} \frac{x}{4}.$ Draw the associated triangle.

Comment: You could at least make the trivial simplification before asking for help, otherwise it looks like you didn't even try.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\sec^{-1}(\frac{x}{4})=\alpha$$

$$\sec\alpha=\frac{x}{4}$$
then
$$\cos\alpha = \frac{4}{x}$$

and

$$\sin\alpha = \frac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac1{16}\sin(\sec^{-1}(\frac x4))=\frac1{16}\sin(\cos^{-1}(\frac 4x))=\frac1{16}\sqrt{1-(\frac4x)^2}=\frac1{16}\sqrt{1-\frac{16}{x^2}}=\frac x{16x}\sqrt{1-\frac{16}{x^2}}=\frac 1{16x}\sqrt{x^2-16}=\frac {\sqrt{x^2-16}}{16x}$$

Here, we make progress by first adjusting $\sec^{-1}(y)=\cos^{-1}(\frac1y)$, then by using the identity $\sin(\cos^{-1}(y))=\sqrt{1-y^2}$, and then simply applying basic algebra

Answer (score 1):

Cancel common factor in denominator.

An elementary trig drawing is helpful. ( An elementary approach is better than bringing in derived trig ratios). The right triangle's vertical side is computed using Pythagoras thm. Read the sin ratio off the marked angle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since $\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)=1$ and $\cos(\theta) = \frac{1}{\sec(\theta)} $then
$\require{cancel}$
$$
\sin(\theta) =\pm \sqrt{1-\cos^2(\theta)} =\pm \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\sec^2(\theta)} } = \pm\sqrt{\frac{\sec^2(\theta) -1}{\sec^2(\theta)}}
$$
where the sign depends on whether $\sin(\theta)$ is positive or negative. Taking $\theta = \mathrm{arcsec}\left(\frac{x}{4} \right)$, since $\mathrm{arcsec}\left(\frac{x}{4} \right)\in [0, \pi]$ then $\sin\left(\mathrm{arcsec}\left(\frac{x}{4} \right)\right) \ge 0$, so we take the $\color{purple}{\text{positive}}$ sign:
$$
\sin\left(\mathrm{arcsec}\left(\frac{x}{4} \right)\right) =\color{purple}{+}\sqrt{\frac{\cancel{\sec}^2\left(\cancel{\mathrm{arcsec}}\left(\frac{x}{4} \right)\right) -1}{\cancel{\sec}^2\left(\cancel{\mathrm{arcsec}}\left(\frac{x}{4} \right)\right)}} = \sqrt{\frac{\frac{x^2}{16}-1}{\frac{x^2}{16}}} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}{|x|}
$$
and multiplying by $\frac{1}{16}$ on both sides (and assuming $x>0$ to remove the absolute value) gives your result.